# How to get approval status of a list item as a column to that list?

Tags: list, workflow, custom-list, tasks, task-list

I have a Calendar list and an approval workflow. The workflow is initiated when a new item is added. The event gets approved in the task list. I want to get that "Outcome" column to the list. But when I tried adding the new column to the list by using "Lookup Field" as a column and add "Outcome" from the task list, it didn't work.

The workflow is as follows,

->Calendar Item created -> Email sent -> adds a new item to task list -> task list item is approved.

I want that approved status (also known as "Outcome" column) to be displayed in the calendar list item.

**Updated:**
When I am trying to add a new column to the calendar list, I click "Lookup" field and this is what I got. Approval Status is a task list. But I am not able to see any calendar item id. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the task is created, it creates an output variable of the Task List item ID. Use that variable to look up the outcome from the task list and update the calendar list item with that value from your workflow.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: You would be doing that in the workflow itself, not creating a new lookup column. Create a new single line of text column, and using the method I describe, in the workflow set the field value. You'll also need a workflow on the task list to update that field when the task item changes.