# Unable to add "Approval status" site column to my page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-site, publishing-page, site-column

I am working on a publishing site collection using the enterprise wiki template. now i want to modify my enterpriseWiki.aspx page layout using SharePoint designer, to add the site column named "Approval Status" .

But the problem i am facing is that i can not find the "Approval status" column inside the site columns, or inside the avialble content types? so can anyone advice how i can add "Approval status" site column to my page layout and to set the column as read-only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you enabled Content Approval for your page library, you will see "Approval status" column added automatcially.

Comment: i already enable the content approval for the library. and the approval status column will be displayed inside the "All documents", "Approve/reject" & "My submission" views. but i want to add this column to the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page layout, but i can not find this column inside the site columns or inside the available content types....

Comment: See if this discussion give some some help? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67500/how-to-get-approval-status-of-a-list-item-as-a-column-to-that-list